# Custom UITableViewCell elements getting cut off in the Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm just getting started with iOS development. I am trying to make a custom UITableViewCell for an iPad-only app.

I am using XCode 4.2 and the latest iOS 5 Beta.

When I'm trying to build my interface, I can't place an elements or make any elements wider than about half of the cell size that's displayed. In the screenshot attached, I want to place the "Name" label on the far right side and stretch the progress bar to the far right side as well. However, when I stretch the progress bar out any further, it just gets cut off.

I'm sure I'm missing something...any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this, as well.  Very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

If it is allowing you to stretch the progress bar the entire length and then cuts it off after you release it, then there is probably another object (i.e. custom button, image view, etc) on the right portion of your cell that is higher on the view stack.

Check in the Objects section of Interface Builder to see if that is the case.  Then you can adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll like to make a little guess here...does it have to do with the orientation of landscape/portrait? It looks like the cell is landscape but the view is only for portrait...

Answer (score 0):

check every controller with background color property. set the different color for every one. Might be it's overlapped one view over second view.